# Were passive and active gravitational mass actually ever considered to be different? If yes, why?

Tags: gravity, mass, history

Mass produces gravity and is subject to it. It seems impossible to separate the two phenomena and the equivalence of the two forces was stated centuries ago.

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass#Phenomena) considers measuring two different gravitational masses - active and passive. It also states that:

> Although some theorists have speculated that some of these phenomena
>   could be independent of each other.

So did physicists actually ever consider the possibility of different values for active and passive gravitational masses? If so, why might have they *expected* them to be different and caused by independent phenomena?

Comment: Maybe in your second case you're referring to test particles? Often when treating gravity we consider a configuration of masses and the trajectory of a "test particle" which we consider to have a non zero mass but small enough that its influence on the other masses is negligible, i.e. we consider as if the test particle feels the gravitational field but doesn't produce one of its own (it produces one, but it's too small to matter). Though it's just a convenient approximation to see trajectories, not something physical

Comment: @JohnRennie, is there another way to explain the separation between the two phenomena? That is basically my question.

Comment: Yes, there was an empirical reason for equating gravitational and inertial masses: bodies fall at the same rate of acceleration irrespective of their masses/composition. See my answer here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/431222/133418

Comment: Theoretical speaking, you can't separate the two things. In fact, geometrically, gravity is nothing but a deformation of the spacetime, and every particle with or without mass will move according to the geometry of the spacetime (This is General Relativity).

Comment: @Avantgarde, the problem here is **not** equivalence between inertial and gravitational mass, but the necessary equivalence betweenpassiv and active gravitational mass

Comment: @KevinDeNotariis, yes, that is with hindsight, but at the time GR was not in sight. What provoked such an absurd, impossible distinction?

Comment: @user157860 Ah, okay. A priori, active and passive gravitational masses represent distinct properties of a system. That you could think of equating them comes from assuming/imposing Newton's 3rd law or conservation of momentum.

Comment: @Avantgarde, anyway you look at it, such distinction is preposterous, that is my remark, but the question stands, what made them consider that possibility?

Comment: @user157860 It might seem obvious, as many other things in physics, because the symmetry principle in play is obvious. There's no reason to have the symmetry exist in *every* situation. If the symmetry is broken in some situation, we could expect different results.

Comment: @Avantgarde, of course, the question asks what special condition led them to consider that might be the case